# How to update linq query result

Tags: c#, linq

I will explain my issue using example.

lets say I have `linq` query result.

```
var result1=from c in client
    select new my_type
    {
        ...
            stockDesctiption=??

    };
```

We will say `Client` has filed called **stockId**. this is the same as **stockId** in the `dammadgeStockHistory` table. these table are not connected in any foreign key constrain.

if i need to get the `dammadgeStockHistory.stockDescrption` for each client how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Join tables by this field (foreign key constraint is not required for that):

```
var result1 = from c in client
              join dsh in dammadgeStockHistory 
                  on c.stockId equal dsh.stockId
              select new my_type
              {
                stockId = c.stockId,
                // ...                  
                stockDesctiption = dsh.stockDescrption
              };
```

UPDATE If you want to do 'left join':

```
var result1 = from c in client
              join dsh in dammadgeStockHistory 
                  on c.stockId equal dsh.stockId into g
              from cdsh in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new my_type
              {
                stockId = c.stockId,
                // ...                  
                stockDesctiption = cdsh == null ? null : dsh.stockDescrption
              };
```

Comment: joining will show only the clients who has a dammadgeStockHistory. But i need to get all the clients along with the stockDescrption

Comment: @NewDeveloper no problem, updated code. When you doing *join..into* (i.e. group join) then `g` will contain all damadgeStockHistory entries joined with clien (one entry or no entries I believe)